# kafka + how to calculate the value of log.retention.byte

Tags: apache-kafka

One of the major role of **log.retention.byte** parameter is to avoid full size of the kafka disk , or in other words purging of data logs in order to avoid kafka disk full

According to the following link: 
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_kafka-component-guide/content/kafka-broker-settings.html

log.retention.bytes – is The amount of data to retain in the log for each topic partition. By default, log size is unlimited.

We can see also the Note -  that this is the limit for each partition, so multiply this value by the number of partitions to calculate the total data retained for the topic.

In order to understanding it well Let’s give  little example ( hands-on is always much better)

In kafka machine Under /var/kafka/kafka-logs we have the following topic partitions , while Topic name is - lop.avo.prt.prlop

example of topics partitions under /var/kafka/kafka-logs

```
lop.avo.prt.prlop-1
lop.avo.prt.prlop-2
lop.avo.prt.prlop-3
lop.avo.prt.prlop-4
lop.avo.prt.prlop-5
lop.avo.prt.prlop-6
lop.avo.prt.prlop-7
lop.avo.prt.prlop-8
lop.avo.prt.prlop-9
lop.avo.prt.prlop-10
```

and under each partition we have the following logs ( example )

```
4.0K    00000000000000023657.index
268K    00000000000000023657.log
4.0K    00000000000000023657.timeindex
4.0K    00000000000000023854.index
24K     00000000000000023854.log
4.0K    00000000000000023854.timeindex
```

In the cluster we have 3 kafka machines ( 3 brokers ) 
About kafka storage – each kafka include disk with size of 100G

let’s say that we want to purge the logs in the topic when disk comes to 70% from the total disk ,

so now let’s try to calculate the value of **log.retention.bytes** according to the above info

because we have 10 topic partitions and the we want to limit the total size of the disk to 70G

then my assumption is to do the calculate as the following

each partition will limit to 7G and 7G translating to bytes , so it is  7516192768  bytes

7G X 10 = 70G  ( 70% from the total disk )

So seems that **log.retention.bytes** should set to 7516192768 , in order to limit each partition to 7516192768 bytes

Dose my assumption is logical?

If not then what is the right calculation of - **log.retention.bytes**
?  , based on that kafka disk is 100G ,  and we have only 10 topic partitions under /var/kafka/kafka-logs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kafka + how to avoid kafka disk to became 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52970153/kafka-how-to-avoid-kafka-disk-to-became-100)

Comment: no duplicate because the answer from  kafka + how to avoid kafka disk to became 100% not explain how to tune the log.retention.byte

Comment: the target of my question is to understand how to calculate the log.retention.byte according to my cluster and disk size , since the calculation isn't part of my previos question , then I ask this current question

Comment: In my answer, I have explained what factors should be taken into account in order to avoid exceeding disk storage.

Comment: yes but , in my case we have 3 kafka machines , and I want to avoids the case that disk will reached the 70% , so not clearly how to do that , if you want you can add the additional info on my previous question and I will delete this question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just a couple of things to keep in mind:

- `log.retention.bytes` defines how much data Kafka will ensure is available. So this is a **lower bound limit**. The maximum size on disk can be hard to exactly calculate as it depends on a number of settings like Segments and Indexes size, Segment roll time, cleaner interval (most `log.*` settings). See [Kafka retention policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823569/kafka-retention-policies/51827267#51827267) for some more details.

  Planning for 70% of total disk usage is a good idea but in practice I'd still recommend to monitor your disk usage to avoid surprizes.
- Based on your calculation, you are likely to require changes if you want to add partitions. Also note that replicas have to be counted, so if you create 1 new partitions with replication factor 3, 3 brokers will need to have the space available.